# Understanding Decode Function In SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Can someone please explain me how the decode function works in SQL ? I am trying to understand this line

```
DECODE(table1.R1_REGION, 'Y','Y',DECODE(table1.R2_REGION,'Y','Y','N')) R1_OR_R2_REGION
```

I am not sure how this field R1_OR_R2_REGION is getting populated using the decode fn.

Comment: You tagged this for `MySQL` and `SQL Server`.  I don't believe either of those databases has a `DECODE` function.  My guess is that you're actually using Oracle which does have this function but isn't tagged in your question.

Comment: Which database are you actually using

Comment: Thank you so much  ! yes, I am using Oracle

Answer (score 0):

`DECODE` is explained in documentation; in simple cases, it is easy to understand. When things get complex, `DECODE` becomes real pain to write, maintain and understand.

Lucky us, we have `CASE` which is way simpler. Perhaps it would be easier for you to understand if `DECODE` you posted is rewritten to the following expression:

```
#1 case when table1.r1_region = 'Y' then 'Y'
#2     else case when table1.r2_region = 'Y' then 'Y'
#3               else 'N'
            end
   end r1_or_r2_region
```

That's exactly what `DECODE` does (match numbers in `CASE` with these in `DECODE`):

```
DECODE(table1.R1_REGION, 'Y','Y',DECODE(table1.R2_REGION,'Y','Y','N')) 
       ------------------------  ------------------------------  ---                      
       #1                        #2                              #3
```

- if `table1.r1_region` is equal to `Y`, then the result is `Y`
- otherwise, check whether `table1.r2_region` is equal to `Y`

  - if so, the result is `Y`
  - otherwise, result is `N`

Comment: It would be more precise to match `decode` with [`simple_case_expression`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/img_text/simple_case_expression.html) with the exception that `decode` treats two nulls as equal

Comment: Thank you so so much ! I am new to learning SQL and, DECODE is a pain I agree. This makes a lot more sense ! Thank you !